# pytest fixture returning 'function' object instead of a dictionary

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I'm trying to use my fixture below on one of my pytest scripts.

If I add `back_up_account` as a param, it works fine and returns a dictionary:

```
def tests_123(self, default_user):

    self.startup(default_user(back_up_account="test_account123"))
```

But if I don't add `back_up_account` as a param, it doesn't work and returns 'function' object.

```
def tests_123(self, default_user):

    self.startup(default_user)
```

Does anybody know why?

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def default_user(self) -> Dict:

        user = None

        def return_account(back_up_account: str = None):
            try:
                #self.user_util.get_account() returns a Dictionary
                user = self.user_util.get_account()
            except Exception:
                return back_up_account
            return user
        yield return_account
```

Comment: It should return user, which is defined in user = self.user_util.get_account(). and get_account returns a dictionary

Comment: how about updating the last line: `yield return_account()`

Comment: In the first case you call default_user and get its return value which is a dictionary, in the second case you don't call the function and get the function itself, not its return value.

Comment: @Maciek
If i do yield return_account(), it's returning 'NoneType' object

Comment: @mkrieger1 How do you go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

### PROBLEM:

You can't get a dictionary, so you get the `'function' object` problem, because you're returning a function.

### SOLUTION:

In your `default_user` function, to get the dictionary you need to:

1. Add `account__user = default_user()`
2. Replace `self.startup(default_user)` with `self.startup(account__user)`, writing in the brackets what you created in step 1.

Code:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def default_user(self) -> Dict:

        user = None

        def return_account(back_up_account: str = None):
            try:
                #self.user_util.get_account() returns a Dictionary
                user = self.user_util.get_account()
            except Exception:
                return back_up_account
            return user
        yield return_account


        def tests_123(self, default_user):

            account__user = default_user()
            self.startup(account__user)
```

Comment: @blue92138 If this answer helped you and it is the solution you were looking for, please accept the answer as per the Stackoverlow rules. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether your fixture is of type Dict or of type Callable returning dict. If you are using an IDE with type checking, it will have already been complaining to you about this.  Take its warnings seriously, they will usually be very helpful.

With `yield return_account` you are yielding / returning a function.  Thus it *is* a function and you must *call* it using parenthesis (or supplying an optional parameter).  If you want it to be a dict then return a dict (by *calling* the function as @maciek pointed out).  But if you return a dict, you cannot also use it as a function in cases where you want to override 'backup_account'.

If providing that optional backup_account is a necessity, then just accept that you have a callable and use it as such. Always. And update your fixture's type annotation to accurately show its usage.

```py
# The only way to do correct typing here is to define a Protocol or class
# There's no other way to show that the argument is optional. Defining 
# this here for interest but really it is probably overkill
class ReturnsUserDict(Protocol):
  def __call__(self, back_up_account: Optional[str] = None) -> Dict:
      ...

class Test....:
  @pytest.fixture
  def default_user(self) -> ReturnsUserDict:
     def return_account(back_up_account: Optional[str] = None) -> Dict:
        try:
            return self.user_util.get_account()
        except Exception:
            # FIX ME - this line returns a string, not a Dict. Again, be
            # consistent. Add logic here which uses that string to
            # produce a meaningful User Dict that is just like the one
            # returned from get_account() above

            return back_up_account

     yield return_account

  def test_one(default_user):
     my_user = default_user()
     assert my_user["awesome"] == "so awesome"

  def test_two(default_user):
     some_other_user = default_user("backup_username")
     assert some_other_user["testing some key in dict"] == "expected value"
```

Also, your fixture name `default_user` implies a user instance. Since it is really a factory, I'd recommend naming your fixture "default_user_factory"